# updated text is not getting updated on the Wordpress page immediately every time it needs a hard refresh how to solve this issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a admin page where i update number in text-box it gets updated and inserted in database and from there it gets displayed on page but updated text is not getting updated on WordPress page immediately every time it needs a hard refresh (through hard refresh plugin or I have to activate or deactivate WordPress theme) how to solve this issue. please help. here is my complete code please try to help. first admin page:

```
<?php
use Gt\Gt\Database\Database;
extract($_POST);
if(isset($save))
{
    DataBase::getupdate($ticketsavailable); 
    header('location: http://localhost:82/?page_id=1000');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>update page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="" method="POST">
 <label class="update_heading"> UPDATE </label>  
  <label for="update" class="update"> Update Number: </label><input type="textbox" id="ticketsavailable" name="ticketsavailable" value="<?php
                         echo  $ticketleft[0]->ticket_available ;?>" >
                         <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>


//getupdate() functions
public static function getupdate($ticketsavailable)
    {
        global $wpdb;       
        $wpdb->insert( 
            'tickets_available', 
            array( 
                'ticket_available' => $ticketsavailable

            ), 
              array(  
                  '%s', 

              ) 
            );

        $last_donation_id = $wpdb->insert_id;   
        return $last_donation_id;   
    }
```

I have Installed wordpress plugin to excecute php code on wordpress page:
now this number is displayed on wordpress page through this code:

```
global $wpdb;
 $eventslist = $wpdb->get_results("select ticket_available from tickets_available order by id desc limit 1");
 $tickets_left = $eventslist[0]->ticket_available;
 echo $tickets_left;
```

number is getting updated and displayed on wordpress page but its hard refresh every time,please help.

Comment: It seems like your site is storing cache that's why it is causing issue clear your cache and then try again or install [wp super cache plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/)  and remove all the cache it will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried clearing the cache but still its not getting displayed immediately

Comment: How did you remove the cache have you installed wp_super_cache plugin?

Comment: By clearing history, and I have not installed wp_super_cache plugin, Is it Safe? because Iam working on LIVE server.

Comment: Yes it is safe as I use this plugin in almost every site you can use that plugin